# Store project files in VSTS

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

I am  working for product team which only build plugins (add-ons) to the main product. Becasue of this reason each add-on is a project file which i need to store in my TFS. recently i have decided to move to VSTS and i have a confused the way i should store these visual studio projects.

1. My management will not allowed me to create new project for each .csproj file (add-on)
2. would it be good idea to create repository for each .csproj file (add-on) inside one vsts project ?
3. is there limitation for number of repos in vsts project?

Comment: Have you considered just creating separate folders for each project in a single VSTS project?

Comment: that is a good idea. can i still do builds.

Comment: Absolutely. You'll need Solutions for each of the projects if you want to build them independently, or you can create larger solutions to build one or more projects at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limitation of repositories for a VSTS team project, you can create the number of repositories as you need.

> would it be good idea to create repository for each .csproj file
>   (add-on) inside one vsts project ?

Not exactly.

- For related projects, you should manage them in the same git repo (for different branches if needed). And it will benefit for you to build/release the projects.
- For unrelated projects, you can manage them in different git repositories.